# Can't read property 'path' while uploading file

Tags: node.js

Hi i am just trying to learn node js and i am trying to upload a file to different location in my computer but i am facing some issues...Here is my code...

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require('formidable');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if(req.url == '/upload'){
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
            var newpath = 'E:/Node/ResumeUpload/' + files.filetoupload.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath,newpath,function(err){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                res.write('File uploaded sucessfully to ' + newpath);
                res.end();
            }) 
        });
    }
    else{
        fs.readFile('FileUpload.html',function(err,data){
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
}).listen(9090);
```

But the problem is it is showing error as below

```
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at E:\Node\FileUploading.js:8:46
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (E:\Node\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:107:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (E:\Node\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:557:8)
    at E:\Node\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:238:12
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (E:\Node\node_modules\formidable\lib\file.js:79:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:208:7)
```

Can anybody suggest what would be the reason for this issue...!!

Thank You.

Comment: Isn't `files` array? So you need to use `files[0].filetoupload.path;`

Comment: @iofjuupasli still not working...same error....

Answer (score 0):

You can use try module multer in nodejs, you can upload file, you can see:[Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```html
//install multer
$ npm install --save multer
```